# How to find which screen is called from which program?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have to see which screen is called from which program. Is there any table that contain called screen entries in SAP ABAP.

Comment: A screen is called from the program it belongs to. Could you please give details about the context, what do you exactly need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check tables:

1. `T185V` - subscreens
2. `D020T` - screens/progs
3. `TRDIR` - common program catalog